# Cannot download file from S3 bucket

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to download an object from my S3 bucket using boto in FastAPI with Docker and the following issue was found:

**FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory**

However, when I tried to download the object from S3 in FastAPI without Docker, it worked.

My code:

```
aws_s3 = boto3.Session(aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
                                aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY).resource('s3')

aws_s3.meta.client.download_file(
    bucket_name, object, path)
```

I can confirm that the path is correct.

The error are as follows:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '{path}.xlsx.A9c02F22'

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '{path}.xlsx.D6Ddda5f'
```

I am using the following Boto3 sdk version:

```
boto3=1.24.6, botocore=1.27.6
```

Comment: what does `path` and `object` contain?

Comment: object here is the excel file that i need to download and patch is the patch to the excel file

Comment: "No such file or directory" is typically a local error.  I don't think it's a boto3/aws error message.  Make sure `path` is correct.

Comment: on an unrelated note, putting those long term API credentials in code is a pretty bad idea. If you use [an alternate method](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/credentials.html#configuring-credentials), your creds will be more secure, and your code will be more portable.  When you're interacting with AWS through SDKs, you should not expect to do anything special in your code to find credentials.  Put them somewhere boto3 expects, and you can create your clients directly with `boto3.client('s3')` and call `download_file` from there.

Comment: There are multiple issues opened for this error on boto3 github: https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/3340
This is most likely due to your Docker container

Comment: Does the error message literally contain '{path}' or did you substitute that to hide the real path?